# AngularJS ngResource: How to always use the same catch function?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

Every time I hit the servers using any $resource I want to show the same alert to my users whenever it fails.

Today, it looks like:

```
function tryAgain() { alert("try again") }
myResource.query().$promise.catch(tryAgain);
myResource.update(...).$promise.catch(tryAgain);
myResource.delete(...).$promise.catch(tryAgain);
otherResource.query().$promise.catch(tryAgain);
```

Is there a way to configure the default error handling function for ngResource? I'm looking for something like:

```
$resource.somethingMagicHere.defaults.catch(tryAgain);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) in your `app.config()` section. This will catch all response errors originating from `$http` which `$resource` uses.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
  return {
    'responseError': function(response) {
      if (response.status == 401) {
        // Handle 401 error code
      }
      if (response.status == 500) {
        // Handle 500 error code
      }

      // Always reject (or resolve) the deferred you're given
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: It did the trick. Thanks! And I didn't pass the $injector to the function.

Answer (score 1):

The @kba answer helped me find the path. The following article made me understand it:

http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Just declare it once and reuse:

```
var defaultErrorHandler = function() {
  alert("try again")
}

myResource.query(...).$promise.catch(defaultErrorHandler());            
myResource.update(...).$promise.catch(defaultErrorHandler());
...
```

Comment: Actually, that's what I have today. That doesn't look good because I have to repeat code frequently. I'm looking for something like configuring the default behaviour of ng-rsource.

Comment: Well, in your sample you have copied the function. When you define it globally you can maintain it in one place. I'm not aware of a *default error handler* for `ngResource`.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear at first. I have updated my question. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: I guess you should not invoke, just pass it as a 'reference', 
myResource.query(...).$promise.catch(defaultErrorHandler); it will auto-invoke on exception, won't it?